# Lost Context when Using 'this' within Prototype Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prototype

Ok, so I have a node application that uses express.  Within this application I have an express route like so:

```
var   MyObj = require('./myObj')
    , myObj = new MyObj();    
app.post('/api/blah', auth.requiresLogin, myObj.method2);
```

Now within the MyObj object I have the following:

```
var MyObj = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.message = 'hello';

};

MyObj.prototype = {
  method1: function(req, res, done){
    console.log('In Method 1');
    done(null, this.message +' '+this.name);
  },
  method2: function(req, res){

    var message;

    console.log('In Method 2');

    this.method1(req, res, function(err, value){
      if(err) throw err;
      message = value;
      console.log(this.message);
    });

    return message;
  }
};

module.exports = MyObj;
```

Now if I dont require this object and call it from within the same file it works. As demonstrated on this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/britztopher/qCZ2T/.  However, if i require it, construct it with new, and try to call `myObj.method2(req, res);` from the requiring class I get `#<Object> has no method 'method1'`.  Dont know what I am doing wrong here, or if its expressJS or require JS thats giving me issues.  Also, when i look inside `this` when in method2 it is `this = global`, so something is losing this' context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing the `myObj.method2` method as a parameter to `app.post` you are not telling in which context/scope it should execute. Therefore it will execute in the global scope. The solution should be `myObj.method2.bind(myObj)`.

Comment: this did end up working, thanks for that!!  I do have a follow up question.  Why isnt the context bound to MyObj upon instantiation?  I noticed that when i inspected within the c'tor at runtime using webstorm that `this` referred to MyObj and had its prototype defined also.  Is there a cleaner way to do this or is this the only way to inform the method which context/scope to use?

Comment: There is no short answer to that. I recommend you googling "javascript scope". This is a good writeup: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/